# What's the difference between error and fail?

Tags: haskell, error-handling

I've been looking for answer for this question and found [this blog post](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors). It says that `fail` has advantages over `error` because it isn't constrained to the `IO` monad.

Should i use `fail` instead of `error` all over my code? Does `fail` raise `Control.Exception.catch`able exceptions in `IO`?

**EDIT:** I've found [an update](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/08/8-ways-to-report-errors-in-haskell-revisited/) for the link above.

Comment: In `IO`, `fail = error` (with possibly some extra text added to the error message), so it is as `catch`able as `error`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my advice:

- If you're in `IO` code already, use proper exceptions via `throwIO` from `Control.Exception`.
- If your code uses a monad stack already, add errors to your monad stack if it doesn't support it already, and use those.
- If you are in non-monadic code, write total functions. I.e., avoid `error` and incomplete patterns if you can. Using `fail` here would only force your code to be unnecessarily monadic. If you need exceptional results, use a proper data type (such as `Maybe` or `Either` or a custom datatype).

Comment: Minor tweak: I would say to use `throwIO` instead of `throw`.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman You're absolutely right. That's what I meant. Edited.

Comment: I'd argue there's one correct place to use `error`. That's when code has preconditions not expressed in its type, and those are violated. That is, when code failed because of a programmer error, not bad input.

Comment: @Carl I agree that there are certain situations where it's reasonable to use `error`. I still think that it can't be bad to always have a slightly guilty feeling even then, because it's all too easy to make wrong assumptions about internal invariants :)

Comment: @Carl: I won't say that I do this, but I think in those circumstances it would be even better to use `throw` with a custom exception type, as that can ultimately give better information than a simple string. The overhead of doing that can be a bit large, so it's probably not worth it most of the time.